# How can I parse this language in Java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, lexical-analysis

Sorry for the vague title, I didn't know how to describe the problem with just one line.

Basically I'm trying to build a simple parser (manually) for a language with a syntax similar to XML, like this:

```
<my_language check="somestring">
    *strings here*
</my_language>
```

Where *strings here* means that inside that there could be anything (but most likely code from another language).
An example of complete code could be something like this:

```
<my_language check="House">
    House myHouse = new House();
     house.setAdress("somewhere");
</my_language>

<my_language check="House/Garage">
    Garage myGarage = new Garage();
    garage.setCar("some car");
</my_language>
```

The sense of the language is not really relevant right now. What I need is a way to parse this, using a recursive descent parser (made with just a syntax analyzer and a lexical analyzer).

The grammar for the syntax analyzer is not really a problem... what I'm struggling to make is the lexical analyzer that finds the tokens I need.

I recently made another parser similar to this for a language more similar to XML, and I used a StreamTokenizer for the lexical analyzer. In this case though I don't know how can I use it.

With a StreamTokenizer I could easily split the parts like "my_language check="House">" into tokens, but then I would need to take the code inside the tags as a whole (leaving the format intact) and I don't know how can I do that. Basically I would need to take the whole code block instead of word for word, but I know that the StreamTokenizer can't let me do that.

So, what approach should I use?

Comment: Most existing XML-parsers should be able to handle that, no need to write your own.

Comment: Your example is so close to XML and SOAP... Can you not create a transformer which transforms this to valid XML? Then you can use all the XML libraries out there to do your parsing

Comment: I'm aware that there are already made parser or parser generators out there that could do the job for me, but I'm trying to do this as an exercise in order to learn about parsing simple things using an actual language. So to answer your questions, I need to parse it on my own as it is, without transformations to other languages.

Comment: Use a regular expresion

Comment: If you are doing this as an exercise in order to learn something then why are you asking SO to do it for you. What have you tried? What doesn't work? Post your code.

Comment: How can I use a regular expression? I've tried that plus a Scanner but I can't get proper regular expressions to get the tokens I want. I'm definitely NOT asking for a solution, I'm asking for HELP in finding it, that's a whole difference. I've already written what I tried (using the StreamTokenizer), there's no need to post code. The problem with the StreamTokenizer (as I said) is that I can't get the whole string inside a tag, it only gives me word by word. I looked everywhere on the internet, but I can't find a class that would help me... or maybe I'm missing a keyword to search.

Comment: So I'm here because I'm out of options and I'm looking for help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Go read a document on any lexer generator; that will show you that they use regular expressions to "build a lexer".

Comment: My suggestion will be to go with easy route, and define your grammar and plug it into Antlr. Antlr will generate lexer and parser for you.